# iccube : is there a way to display the Total of each column on a Stacked column AMchart?

Tags: amcharts, iccube-reporting

Using iccube 6.5.2, I want to diplay the total (sum) of each column of a stacked column am chart. 
It seems to be doable as amchart does it ([sample amchart](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/display-sum-real-values-stacked-columns/))

Question : is there a way to do this using iccube reporting standard functions ?

(remark, I also want to display the values of each cell of the column)

Comment: Sorry. Nothing out of the box, would need some development effort